# Calling a function inside a listener is showing me a IllegalStateException

Tags: java, exception, listener, call, skype

I'm trying to integrate Java Skype API in my program. I found an example code in the API documentation that was using Java listeners to get the current call status. I implemented the code in my program and I need to call a function (addLog function) every time the Skype call status changes, but when I call such function, the console is showing me a "`Exception in thread "AsyncSkypeMessageSender-18" java.lang.IllegalStateException`".

When I use the command `System.out.ln` inside the listener, it is working how it is supposed to, without any errors, but every time I call a function inside the listener, it gives me an error.

Do you guys know something to solve my problem, I thought it may be a thread related issue, but I'm not familiar with Java programming.

The code is:

```
public void addLog(String log){
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat datetime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM hh:mm:ss");
    String datetimeString = datetime.format(date);
    logArea.appendText(datetimeString + " > " + log);
}

public void makeCall() throws SkypeException {

    Skype.call("echo123");

    Skype.setDaemon(false);
    //Skype.setDebug(true);

    System.out.println(" --------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ------ Fazendo ligação... ------");
    System.out.println(" --------------------------------");

    SkypeVoicer skypeVoicer = new SkypeVoicer();
    skypeVoicer.addLog("Iniciou ligação\n");

    Skype.addCallListener(new CallAdapter() {
        public void callMaked(Call makedCall){
            makedCall.addCallStatusChangedListener(new CallStatusChangedListener(){

                @Override
                public void statusChanged(Status status) throws SkypeException {
                    if(status == Status.FINISHED){
                        System.out.println("Finalizou, chamada de " + makedCall.getDuration() + " segundos...");
                        skypeVoicer.addLog("\nFinalizou em "+makedCall.getDuration()+" segundos");
                        makedCall.removeCallStatusChangedListener(this);
                    }
                    else if(status == Status.CANCELLED){
                        System.out.println("Cancelado");
                    }
                    else if(status == Status.ROUTING){
                        System.out.println("Redirecionando...");
                    }
                    else if(status == Status.RINGING){
                        System.out.println("Tocando...");
                    }
                    else if(status == Status.INPROGRESS){
                        System.out.println("Em Progresso...");
                        skypeVoicer.addLog("Em Progresso...");
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });

}
```

The full stack trace is this one bellow:

> Exception in thread "AsyncSkypeMessageSender-18"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = AsyncSkypeMessageSender-18    at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(Unknown
>   Source)   at javafx.scene.Scene.addToDirtyList(Unknown Source)    at
>   javafx.scene.Node.addToSceneDirtyList(Unknown Source)     at
>   javafx.scene.Node.impl_markDirty(Unknown Source)  at
>   javafx.scene.shape.Shape.impl_markDirty(Unknown Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text.geomChanged(Unknown Source)    at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_geomChanged(Unknown Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text.needsTextLayout(Unknown Source)    at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Unknown Source)    at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Unknown Source)     at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text$2.invalidated(Unknown Source)  at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)     at
>   javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)  at
>   javafx.scene.text.Text.setText(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin.lambda$new$231(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$$Lambda$172/1330104206.invalidated(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.markInvalid(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.invalidate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.access$1300(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.lambda$new$163(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$$Lambda$77/323047656.invalidated(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextArea$TextAreaContent.insert(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.insertText(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.appendText(Unknown Source)
>     at SkypeVoicer.addLog(SkypeVoicer.java:186)     at
>   SkypeVoicer$2$1.statusChanged(SkypeVoicer.java:157)   at
>   com.skype.Call.fireStatusChanged(Call.java:339)   at
>   com.skype.ConnectorListenerImpl.messageReceived(ConnectorListenerImpl.java:61)
>     at
>   com.skype.connector.Connector.fireMessageEvent(Connector.java:1160)
>     at com.skype.connector.Connector.access$500(Connector.java:37)  at
>   com.skype.connector.Connector$13.run(Connector.java:1139)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Just edited the post with the full stack trace. Thx

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-

Comment: So, I need to use the listener inside the JavaFX runLater function? Thank you for your reply!